# Interchange pages with swipe on small device, show pages next to each other on large device

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

There are two Pages A and B. On a small device, A should be displayed by default and B should be available with a swipe event. On a larger device, both pages should be displayed next to each other.

I really have no clue how to approach this. I tried using another library (iDangero.us swiper) for the swipe, but I am also using knockout.js with a lot of dynamic controls and using swiper in this scenario was quiet a mess (it is tough enough to sync knockout.js and jQuery Mobile). So I plan to fall back to using jQuery Mobile pages and transitions.

Comment: It's quite difficult (maybe infeasible) to do this in jQM, especially putting two pages next to each other. However, a workaround is, on large screens, copy content of both pages into ONE page. on small screens, split them into different pages.

Comment: Thank you, Omar, we will now probably use vertical scrolling on the small device with a break for the larger device - not the original customer specification but feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Iframes if you are familiar with them.

Iframe touch page scrolling may be an issue. But There are various easy solutions.

**Pages structure**

main-page.htm
tablet-page.html
page1.html
page2.html

.

**Jquery to detect screen viewport  width and redirect to the tablet-view if needed.**

in main-page.html file add

```
       $(window).onload(function() {
       var wi = $(window).width();   
        if (wi => 900){         
        window.location.href = 'tablet-page.html';
       };            
       });
```

tablet-view.html has 2 Iframes with page1 and Page2 html links.

**use some css to auto resize the iframes to 50% 50% view. A container may be need.**

result
if its tablet size then

[image]

excuse the bad graphics

Comment: Thanks, like Omar mentioned, it is probably not a good idea to use an UI as per my original question, but if one absolutely had to, then IFrames might be one approach.